# spring data jpa custom query fails to recognize class type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Not able to use custom POJO classes for my spring data jpa queries. Repeatedly fails with the following exception

> "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:
>   com.app.mycompany.AgileCenterServices.entities.ComponentDetailedInfo"*

Tried replacing the custom ComponentDetailedInfo.class and not mentioning anything during the call to entityManager`.createNativeQuery(componentQuery.toString())`, but then Object List returned fails to be converted to the specific POJO class after the query.

```
@Override
public ComponentListResponsePaginated findComponentByProjectId(String projectId, Pageable pageable) { 

logger.info(" Inside findComponentByProjectId() API in IssueComponentServiceImpl");

String componentQuery = "select c.*, u.fullname "
    + "from issue_component c "
    + "left join user u on c.component_lead = u.username "
    + "where "
    + "upper(c.project_id) = upper(" + projectId + ")";

List<ComponentDetailedInfo> compList = new ArrayList<ComponentDetailedInfo>();

try {

logger.info(" ************* Printing query ******************************* ");
logger.info(componentQuery.toString());

compList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(componentQuery.toString(), ComponentDetailedInfo.class)            .setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset())
.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
.getResultList();

}

}
```

Also tried the following

```
List<? extends Object> objList = null;

objList = entityManager.createNativeQuery(componentQuery.toString())              .setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset())
.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
.getResultList();

if(objList != null && objList.size() > 0) {
    for(Object rec: objList) {
       logger.info(" Printing Object ::: " + rec.toString());
       compList.add((ComponentDetailedInfo)rec);
    }
}
```

However the compList fails with the

> **java.lang.ClassCastException**

The custom query returned should get typecast to the specific class type passed to the entityManager`.createNativeQuery`. However, I am facing the exception as mentioned above when I pass the class to `createNativeQuery()`.

Even tried by totally removed the class in the createNativeQuery...

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a constructor result mapping if you want to use a POJO as a result of a native query.

Here is an example query:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(o) as orderCount, AVG(o.price) AS avgOrder " +
    "FROM Customer c " +
    "JOIN Orders o ON o.cid = c.id " +
    "GROUP BY c.id, c.name",
    "CustomerDetailsResult");
```

And that's the mapping you have to add to your Entity:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="CustomerDetailsResult",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass=com.acme.CustomerDetails.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="id"),
                @ColumnResult(name="name"),
                @ColumnResult(name="orderCount"),
                @ColumnResult(name="avgOrder", type=Double.class)})
    })
```

If you don't like that approach you could use QLRM. Learn more about it here: https://github.com/simasch/qlrm